# Jeddict plugin install fails - Apache Netbeans 12 - missing "Maven Projects" plugin dependency

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-12

I am trying to install the Jeddict plugins into Apache Netbeans version 12. I have followed the instructions for both manual install and install via update center:
[Jeddict install instructions](https://jeddict.github.io/page.html?l=p/ucinstallation)

Both methods fail with the following message:

> Some plugins require plugin Maven Projects to be installed.
> The plugin Maven Projects is requested in implementation version 12.0-631bd69cd6112b1cc4c892c24e3e605b1ba04241.
> The following plugin is affected: jCode Util

My Apache Netbeans "about" data is:

> Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0
> Java: 13.0.2; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 13.0.2+9
> Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 13.0.2+9
> System: Linux version 4.15.0-115-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)

If I install the plugins one-by-one, I can get some to install but a fair number of them still fail with the "Maven Projects" dependency. I can't seem to find a plugin with this name. Any help in getting Jeddict to install into an existing Apache Netbeans 12 install would be much appreciated. Thanks to the Jeddict community!

Comment: Have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Here are the steps to install Jeddict on NetBeans 12.

1. Completely uninstall NetBeans 12 IDE including user data folder.
2. Install NetBeans 12 using the installer (one is available for both Mac and Windows).
3. DO NOT UPDATE NetBeans (ensure during install and after install you do not select update NetBeans).
4. Follow instructions on https://jeddict.github.io/page.html?l=p/ucinstallation to install Jeddict plugin
   a. Will need to add https://github.com/jeddict/uc/releases/download/12.0/updates.xml in Plugins Settings.
5. Jeddict should install fine and the Next button on the popup should be selectable after you press Install button.

The process of not installing updates to NetBeans and its plug-ins worked for installing Jeddict on both Windows and Mac for me.